# No data message in ModelSim

Tags: verilog, modelsim, quartus, questasim

```
module barrel(W,Y,S);
    input [3:0] W;
    input [1:0] S;
    output [3:0]Y;
    wire [3:0]T;

    assign {T,Y}={W,W}>>S;
endmodule
```

```
module sim();
    reg  [3:0] W;
    reg [1:0] S;
    wire [3:0] Y ;

    barrel sim1(W, S, Y);
    initial begin
            W = 4'b0100;
            S = 2'b01;
        #10 S = 2'b10;
        #10 S = 2'b11;
        #10 S = 2'b01;

        #10 W = 4'b0110;                
            S = 2'b01;
        #10 W = 4'b0111;
            S = 2'b01;
        #10 W = 4'b1101;
            S = 2'b01;          
    end

    
endmodule
```

These are the two files I am using to try and generate the wave from; however, the "no data" message keeps popping up when I try to simulate the sim.v file.

Comment: Make sure that you have no errors - look how you are instantiating barrel.

Answer (score 0):

in the module :

```
module barrel(W,Y,S);
```

`S` is `input` , `W` is `input`, `Y` is `output`

but look at the test bench you wrote:

```
barrel sim1(W, S, Y);
```

`S` is `reg` , `W` is `reg`, `Y` is `wire`

but when calling the module, you wrote :

```
barrel sim1(W, S, Y);
```

it should be:

```
barrel sim1(W, Y, S);
```

what you did is that you are trying to modify output values (`S`) and expecting input values to change (`Y`)